# What is `curl -o-`?

Tags: curl

I saw on https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm that they would suggest using

```bsh
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
```

to do the installation of `nvm`.  But I searched everywhere and the manpage of `curl` but don't see `curl -o-` (I see `curl -o` but not what `curl -o-` means)

What does it do?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412134/meaning-of-naked-dashes-in-this-curl-tar-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-o` option in the [manpage](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html):

> `-o`, `--output <file>`
>
> Write output to *`<file>`* instead of stdout....

The `-`  after `-o` tells `curl` that the output file is stdout.

Comment: so I think the default is `STDOUT` and so `-o-` is just redundant?

Comment: @nonopolarity, looks like. If I read the man page correctly, it could take multiple `-o` options for multiple files, and in that case, you'd maybe have more use for it

Answer (score 9):

It's an alias for `--output`, which is mentioned a few times in the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/curl.1.html).

> OUTPUT
> If not told otherwise, curl writes the received data to stdout.
> It can be instructed to instead save that data into a local file,
> using the `-o`, `--output` or `-O`, `--remote-name` options.

> OPTIONS
> Options start with one or two dashes. Many of the options require
> an additional value next to them.
>
> `-o`, `--output <file>`
> Write output to `<file>` instead of stdout.
> [...]
> Specifying the output as '-' (a
> single dash) will force the output to be done to stdout.

(`curl -o-` and `curl -o -` act the same.)

Explicitly sending the output to stdout seems a bit redundant, since that's the default anyway. However, the man page does mention using multiple `-o` options for multiple URLs to download, so it might be more useful in that context.